# Assign a property value in a Java class-level annotation

Tags: java, spring, properties, annotations, properties-file

In my `application.properties`, I have a property as this:

```
myAppContext=something.special
```

The Spring app reads the properties from this file.

I want to access the above property in a class-level annotation as this:

```
// "contexts" take in an array of string values
@AClassLevelAnnotation(contexts = {"something.special"})
public class Amazing{}
```

Instead of using the value (which already exists in the properties file) I would like to access it using the property key, something like this, which does not work:

```
@AClassLevelAnnotation(contexts = {@Value("${myAppContext}")})
public class Amazing{}
```

Any suggestion on how this can work?

Comment: Have you tried this? `contexts = "${myAppContext}"`

Comment: Yes, it did not work. It returns `${myAppContext}` not the value of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a bean:

```
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
```

Using @Óscar López's suggestion: `contexts = "${myAppContext}"` That syntax should be working, especially if the property value is a string.

Try this without the brackets first. If you need an array, you may want to consider using a comma-separated value in your application.properties, or even something like `contexts = "#{Arrays.asList(\"${theProperty}\")}"`, with the comma-separated value, if you need a different Collection type.